# SUM(item_name) , should not calculate blank row

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have twenty rows and I am using `sum()`:

```
SELECT Sum(totalcon) AS totalcon_sum,
   Sum(vat3)     AS vat3_sum,
   Sum(rupes)    AS rupes_sum,
   pordernon,
   po_date,
   b_no,
   vendortext
FROM   po,
   potable,
   branch_master,
   delivery_master
WHERE  mr_assetpo = 'NCE'
   AND Substr(po.pordernon, 6, 2) = branch_master.b_no
   AND po.pordernon = delivery_master.deliverypo_no
   AND po.transid = potable.transid
   AND Year(po_date) = '"+req2+"'
   AND status = 'normal'
GROUP  BY Year(po_date)
```

My question is:

Whenever I have blank rows in between sum is counting that row too. I dont want to calculate the empty row.

Comment: Format your code so others can read it.

Comment: Do we really need to see your complete query or can you simplify it to the essential parts?

Comment: Please be more specific. Can you give a simple example, what you think goes wrong and what you'd expect? It is not clear what you mean by 'blank row' here. If it's just a row with all fields set to null, the result shouldn't be different.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "empty row"? Please give us sample data and the execpted output. Ideally as a http://sqlfiddle.com example.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add this

```
   WHERE totalcon != ''
```

or if its null use this

```
   WHERE totalcon is not null
```

Comment: 1 HO 499 06/03/2013 Asha 2 736.00 91.00 827.00 2013-05-07 qwqw 2013-05-06 null
2 bO 499 06/03/2013 Asha 4  736.00 91.00 827.00 2013-03-07 qwqw 2014-05-06 null
                     hp  5
                      ko 3 
                           2944

actual total is 1472 but because of empty row its giving 2944.. how to show only 1472

Answer (score 0):

Use IFNULL function

```
Sum(IFNULL(totalcon,0))
```

Your query should be:-

```
SELECT Sum(IFNULL(totalcon)) AS totalcon_sum,
   Sum(IFNULL(vat3))     AS vat3_sum,
   Sum(IFNULL(rupes))    AS rupes_sum,
   pordernon,
   po_date,
   b_no,
   vendortext
FROM   po,
   potable,
   branch_master,
   delivery_master
WHERE  mr_assetpo = 'NCE'
   AND Substr(po.pordernon, 6, 2) = branch_master.b_no
   AND po.pordernon = delivery_master.deliverypo_no
   AND po.transid = potable.transid
   AND Year(po_date) = '"+req2+"'
   AND status = 'normal'
GROUP  BY Year(po_date)
```